# Is it safe to store 1Password data file on DropBox?

Tags: security, dropbox

I would like to know if it is safe to store the 1Password data file on DropBox?

It can be safely assumed that there are a LOT of people already doing it without any negative security side effects, but I would still like some additional confirmation before taking the plunge.

Comment: It is not safe. Anything that can be hacked will be hacked, and these days it's just not enough to "hack" into something - they also usually release confidential information to prove that they have hacked. If you want garuntees, don't do it. If you're happy with "good-enough" security, then be my guest. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The 1Password people certainly [support using Dropbox](http://help.agilebits.com/1Password3/sync_solutions.html#dropbox).

In general, 1Password uses [good encryption](http://help.agilebits.com/1Password3/sync_solutions.html#dropbox) and Dropbox keeps your files [pretty private](http://www.dropbox.com/help/27).  So if you have a good master password, you shouldn't have to worry.

However, giving anyone else any sort of access to your entire password cache is always going to be less secure than keeping it to yourself.  Whether the benefits outweigh the risks depends on how valuable the information the passwords protect is.

**If you have nuclear launch codes in 1Password, DON'T put them on Dropbox.  Otherwise, GO AHEAD.**

Comment: If you have nuclear launch codes on a networked computer, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) to add another layer of security, and for some extra peace of mind. Just make sure you have a strong master password that's easy to remember.

I've been following Dropbox's recent security challenges. If you're up for some reading, here are some articles that might help you decide.

- May 13, 2011, *Wired* - [Dropbox Lied to Users About Data Security, Complaint to FTC Alleges](http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2011/05/dropbox-ftc/)
- May 16, 2011, *PCWorld* - [Dropbox Drops the Ball on Data Security](http://www.pcworld.com/businesscenter/article/228018/dropbox_drops_the_ball_on_data_security.html)
- May 17, 2011, *PCWorld* - [Dropbox Speaks Out on Data Security Controversy](http://www.pcworld.com/businesscenter/article/228096/dropbox_speaks_out_on_data_security_controversy.html)

Answer (score 2):

[Cloudfogger](http://cloudfogger.com) is a file based encryption tool that uses AES and integrates great with Dropbox, Sugarsync and all the other cloud storage providers.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out this blog post:  [1Password and Dropbox (security tweaks wanted)](http://the.taoofmac.com/space/blog/2011/04/28/2233)

Basically the author points out that there is a text file with entry names and web sites that is not encrypted.  Depending on what you're securing, this may be information that you don't wish to place onto Dropbox.

As an extreme example, if you used 1Password to store your login credentials to a terrorist web site, this file would contain the web site name.  If the NSA was browsing through the contents of your Dropbox, this would raise some red flags.